# Would (cycle-list <ls>) be a bad idea?

Tags: list

Would you consider something like this a bad practice?

```el
(defun cycle-list (ls &optional backward?)
  "Given any list, returns the next element each time it is called."
  (let* ((last-pos (- (length ls) 1))
         (maybe-counter (gethash ls cycle-list-counter))
         (cal-counter (if maybe-counter
                          (if backward?
                              (- maybe-counter 1)
                            (+ maybe-counter 1))
                        0))
         (counter (cond ((> cal-counter last-pos) 0)
                        ((< cal-counter 0) last-pos)
                        (t cal-counter))))
    (puthash ls counter cycle-list-counter)
    (nth counter ls)))
```

I wrote it because it is pretty handy, e.g. I used it to write another function which cycle between themes.

Surely, it shouldn't be used with simple lists, such as `'(1 2 3)`, or in place of `(do-list ...)`. 
But also, say we add one more theme to (custom-available-themes), now the previous hash-key is left unused.

I suppose in this particular case of theme cycling, there is probably a way to deal with this but: I want to know if the function `(cycle-list ...)` itself to you seems bizarre.

Comment: Questions here should be specific straighforward how-to questions, that call for specific, straighforward answers. They should not be about what's "best", what's a "good idea", etc., which solicit primarily opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems with `cycle-list` as you have defined it.

- It seams that you want to apply `cycle-list` on list variables that you actually do not have control of. What happens if someone uses `push`, `delq`, `nconc`, `cl-nset-difference`, or similar functions on such a list? Your counter would be invalidated by that.
- If, because of the previous item, you define your own list, you can choose the type of the list yourself. You actually have a ring-type of list. Depending on the use-case there are built-in types for that. See. e.g., [<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp)Rings")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rings.html) or see how the `kill-ring` is implemented (<kbd>M-:</kbd> [`(info "(elisp)The Kill Ring")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Kill-Ring.html) ).
- The byte-compiler would moan about your code because you use a variable `cycle-list-counter` that is not declared as special with `defvar` or `defvar-local`.  (`defvar` declares the lookup for the `symbol-value` as always dynamically scoped.)
- Currently you do not differentiate between global list variables, buffer-local list variables, and list variables that just have buffer-local values in some buffers. Maybe, that aspect could be fixed by declaring `cycle-list-counter` buffer locally and using either its value or its `default-value`.